# implement a simple back button swift ios

Tags: ios, swift

I have a navigation bar placed directly on my scene. On his I have a navigation item. I can successfully change title on it.

Now I want a back button to appear - I do not need any customization at present, just the ability to catch the click and default ios look for whatever plaform the app is running (Since Swift that is ios7+).

In *viewDidLoad()* I have written

```
outletCatalogNavItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "test", style .plain, target: self, action: "ownbackNavigationFuncCode");
```

In `*ViewDidAppear()*` `outletCatalogNavItem.backBarButtonItem` is non-nil

**Note:** I am not using any shared navigation control across scenes in my storyboard - nor wish to at this point since I am porting an app from another tool/language which has its own navigation/stack logic already (meaning I handle switching and navigation myself in code)

Comment: If you aren't using a UINavigationController then you will need to set the `leftBarButtonItem` not the backBarButtonItem as the latter is used by the UINavigationController

Comment: This appears to to work although the text is so much to the left that some of it is not visible (half a character) - is there any way I can make sure the back button looks native if e.g. some day ios10 looks different than ios7-9?

Comment: Use a UINavigationController :) but if the text is off screen then I would check the constraints you have applied to your UINavigationBar. It should all be on screen

Comment: I think what I need is that back arrow "<" image - anyway to get that image from somewhere?

Comment: Constraints are standard -20 left -20 right

Comment: There is no way you can get it from the operating system. You can make your own or try something like icons8.com. Instead of -20 from leading/trailing margin try 0 from leading/trailing edge

Comment: Menus and data get downloaded online, so I do not have a predefined "item a" opens "scene d". But if UINavigationController can be used together with such a system I will consider it. (Bu fis poorly with my current way I handle navigation logic)

Comment: A navigation comtroller is just a stack of view controllers, so as long as you know the relationship then you can just instantiate the right view controller and put it at the right location in the stack. Even if you didn't come from "a" but want to go back to "a" you can create a new "a" and put it in the stack under the current "b" and then the back item will appear correctly

Comment: @Paulw11 If you make an answer, I will accept it. For now I use leftBarButtonItem - but you answered very much in-depth. And it was acutally rather difficult finding this out because coming from another language/tool the explanation was not intuitive :) For future iOS apps, I should probably use more of ios builtin functionality since I can see how apps can be generated very fast - but for this project I need to maintain as much control as possible + want to port as directly 1:1 as possible

Answer (score 0):

Embed your view controller in a `UINavigationController`. When you `push/segue` to a new view controller the `< Back` button you're looking for will appear on the left hand-side.

Answer (score 0):

```
let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
backItem.title = "Back"
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem
```